# UIWebView load PDF file slowly

Tags: ios, performance, pdf, uiwebview

I am using a uiWebView to display a PDF file. This file is stored in the ipad as a shared file (using iTunes). This is the code I have:

```
NSArray *dirPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *appDicsDir =[dirPath objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *dbPath = [appDicsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@".Bases_de_Datos"];
NSString *pdfBDPath = [dbPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"PlanoInventario.pdf"];

[self.webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:pdfBDPath isDirectory:NO]]];
```

The problem is that the UIWebView takes 5 sec to load. The PDF size is less than 400kb.
How can I improve the speed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: loading speed depends on contents of PDF, and the process running in parallel.

Comment: the content of the PDF is a map

Comment: i've just try with another PDF, it works faster, and the size of the new file is 1.5 mb

Comment: what would be the best way to display the first PDF (1 page, size:400kb) faster??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file size of the PDF isn't what matters - it's the content. Because PDFs can use vector graphics they can display extremely complex things (like, for example, a map) whilst using a minimum of disk space.

A loading time of five seconds or so would not be unusual on iOS for a PDF that was graphically complex. If you need to improve the speed you could think about either regenerating the PDF and rasterizing the vector graphics, or simplify the graphics being displayed so that the device has less to render.

Again, when dealing with PDFs the *content* has much more to do with the loading time than the file size.

Comment: how can I rasterize the PDF file to simplify the graphics?

Comment: rasterize the PDF is a way, but you lose zooming ability ( zoom-in will be blur )